Resize the array environment
I have this MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{lcccccccccccccccccccc}
\text{Operation number} \; i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & \ldots \\
\text{Work} \; W(i)            & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 
\text{Accumulated work} \; A(i) & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & \ldots \\ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}

... which gives me:

I tried to apply scalebox{0.8}{...}, but it gave me errors..

You shouldn't scale elements which contain text. Instead reduce the space between columns and/or choose a smaller font size:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amstext}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}% <- adjust value as required
\begin{array}{lcccccccccccccccccccc}
\text{Operation number} \; i & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & \ldots \\
\text{Work} \; W(i)            & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4  & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\ 
\text{Accumulated work} \; A(i) & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 10  & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & \ldots \\ 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}


For the benefit of future readers, could you briefly describe how you arrived at \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2pt} as a suitable value?

@Mico It's just an example, no complicate process behind it.

I suggest you employ a tabular* environment, with a target width of \textwidth, instead of an array environment. That way, you don't have to work out yourself by how much the intercolumn whitespace has to be reduced in order to make the table fit inside the textblock.

An additional suggestion: Do consider abbreviating "Operation number" and "Accumulated work" to, say, "Op.\ num." and "Accum.\ work". This will allow LaTeX to insert a bit more whitespace between the data columns.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % automatic math mode, right-aligned
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\small % for a 10% linear reduction in font size
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{20}{R} }
Operation number $i$    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & \ldots \\
Work $W(i)$             & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 5  & 0  & 0  & \ldots \\ 
Accumulated work $A(i)$ & 1 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 6 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 15 & 15 & 15 & \ldots \\ 
\end{tabular*}
\end{center}

\end{document}


In my code, I decided to place the tabular* environment inside a center environment in order to have LaTeX automatically insert a bit of whitespace above and below the table.
